# Is it possible to divide a cube into $5772$ cubes of varying sizes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it possible to divide a cube into $5772$ cubes of varying sizes? I'm pretty sure this riddle has to do with algebra and group theory, but so far everything I've tried has led me nowhere. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Fermat's last theorem

Comment: @AvZ I don't mean to follow you around, but this question here sounds interesting to me.  Might you elaborate on your statement?  It is my understanding that Fermat's last theorem is stated as $a^n+b^n=c^n$ has no solutions where $a,b,c$ are all positive integers and $n>2$.  I'm not immediately seeing where that helps us here however as the cubes aren't specified as needing to be of integer (or even rational) length and we have more than two cubes being added.  Is even a generalization of Fermat's last theorem true that $x_1^n+x_2^n+\dots+x_k^n = z^n$ has no solutions?

Comment: @JMoravitz That's what I am wondering...

Comment: A physical cube, or a number that's a perfect cube?

Comment: A physical cube. Thanks for all the replies so far everyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can !

When you have a cube, you can divide that cube into $n^3$ smaller cubes by cutting it into $n$ equal slices along each side. Hence this operation adds $n^3-1$ cubes.

$$5772=1+(17^3-1)+(9^3-1)+(5^3-1)+(2^3-1)$$

So take a cube, and in any order :

- Choose one cube and cut it into $17^3$ cubes
- Choose one cube and cut it into $9^3$ cubes
- Choose one cube and cut it into $5^3$ cubes
- Choose one cube and cut it into $2^3$ cubes

Comment: Very nice indeed. Is there a general statement on just which numbers $n$ have the property that a cube can be cut up into $n$ smaller cubes?

Comment: @Lubin, Following this scenario, for every $n$ of the form
$$n = 1 + \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k (k^3-1),\quad a_k \in \mathbb{N}$$
there is a way to cut a cube into $n$ cubes.
Given any set of positive integers $m_k$, the largest number that doesn't have the form
$$\sum_{k=1} a_k m_k,\quad a_k \in \mathbb{N}$$
is called the [Frobenius number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNumber.html) for that set of numbers. According to WA,
the Frobenius number for $2^3-1, 3^3-1,\ldots$ is $149$. This means for any $n \ge 151$, there is a way to cut a cube into $n$ cubes.

Comment: But, @achillehui, there are other ways to cut a cube up than to take a single one and subdivide it. You can get a cube divided into $20$ subcubes, for instance, by working backwards from a $27$-subdivision. And $20\ne1+k(2^3-1)$. So my question was whether we know exactly which numbers $n$ have the property that a cube may be cut up into $n$ smaller cubes.

Comment: @Lubin I know about that. The more refined way corresponds to breakdown of the form
$$n = 1 + \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k (k^3 - (k-1)^3)$$ and using that, one can show that all $n \ge 71$ is admissible. The key point is there are finitely many exceptions to check and that isn't really anything real special for a $n$ to work. If $n$ is large enough, it will work.

Comment: Ah, good, @achillehui. That’s the kind of information I was looking for.